# export inserted table data to .txt file in SQL server

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I want to export data of inserted table( temporary table have note of inserted data of the table) to .txt file, I used like this inside trigger

```
create trigger monitorTrigger on test 
for insert 
as
declare @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from inserted" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'

exec xp_cmdshell @sql

go
```

this is not working since I didn't give full context(means database.shemaName.tableName) of inserted table. But the same code is working with normal table since I give full context as

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from test2.dbo.test" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'

exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I don't know how to query inserted table in `bcp`, anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do really need a file instantaneously created when data is inserted? You know that if you run three seperate insert statements, only the last insert will be captured in this file? This is a dangerous way to approach this because if there is any issue writing to the file (i.e. if the file is open in excel and locked), the trigger will fail, which means the insert will fail, It's not a good idea to tie external processes to database processes. A more robust way to do this is just schedule an export of the table or queue the changes into a different table which is exported by a different process

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table for temporary storing the results from `INSERTED` before calling `bcp`.

```
create trigger monitorTrigger on test 
AFTER insert 
as
declare @sql varchar(8000)

--delete it every time
TRUNCATE TABLE test2.dbo.tempInserted

--populate it from inserted
INSERT INTO test2.dbo.tempInserted
SELECT * FROM INSERTED

--use it in bcp
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from test2.dbo.tempInserted" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'

exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

**EDIT:**
Apparently this will not work, because table `tempInserted` is locked at the time `bcp` is called.

Here is a workaround idea, maybe not the most elegant solution but should work (if you are not on express edition). You can use trigger just to store the inserted data into this table and you can create a job that runs periodically (every 5 mins let's say) and read from that table, copy to file and delete.

So trigger would be just:

```
create trigger monitorTrigger on test 
AFTER insert 
as
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test2.dbo.tempInserted
  SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

and Stored Procedure to copy to file - that you can run from the job:

```
CREATE PROC transferToFile 
AS
BEGIN
 declare @sql varchar(8000)

 SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from test2.dbo.tempInserted" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'

 exec xp_cmdshell @sql

 --delete at the end
 TRUNCATE TABLE test2.dbo.tempInserted
END
```

Comment: I tried your answer: I have created trigger like you say for test table and I try insert value in test table, the result: it is keep on executing never complete.

Comment: @niren - Apparently table tempInserted is locked at the time bcp is called. Lame. Check the update for workaround idea. Maybe it can work for you. Or I don't know what are you planning to do with the file, but maybe you can just run SP to fill the file when you need it?

Answer (score -1):

I worked so

```
create trigger monitorTrigger on test 
for insert 
as
declare @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from inserted **with (nolock)**" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'

exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

go

Comment: The OP would have to decide if the risks involved in dirty reads would offset the benefits.