# Export values from SQL Server to txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to export values from SQL Server to txt file. I know about BCP, there I need to give either query or table name to export data from a table. I don't want to export data but I want to export values that are assigned to variable. How can I do that, any help?

Comment: What do you mean by `export values assigned to a variable` .. ?

Comment: for e.g: `declare @var int=10`, I want 10 to be there in .txt file

Comment: In Management Studio you can set "Results to Text" option from your commands toolbar (or CTRL+T) and whatever you execute in query windows, results will go to text file

Comment: @NenadZivkovic thanks for your answer, But I want to have .txt file by executing query in the query editor.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I suggested?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I see the result is in text format inside SSMS as per your suggestion, but I want the external .txt file to have the data.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it's not "Results to Text", it should be "Results to File" (CTRL+SHIFT+F)

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I tried with "Results to File" options it's working fine, am getting .txt file as output. But here the "SaveResults" window is popup every time I run query, In my requirement am going to write "export .txt file" code inside trigger. could my requirement be achieve by your suggestion?

Comment: check this link [export inserted table data to .txt file in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628502/export-inserted-table-data-to-txt-file-in-sql-server) this is what I wanted to do at end of the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a query to collect the variables you want to export. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @var1 INTEGER
DECLARE @var2 INTEGER

SELECT @var1 = 10
SELECT @var2 = 22

SELECT 'variable 1' AS VarName, @var1 AS VarValue
UNION
SELECT 'variable 2' AS VarName, @var2 AS VarValue
```

Use this query statement in the following command. Use queryout and replace [querystatement] with the statement above, or use a variable for the query string.

```
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "[querystatement]" queryout "c:\spt_values.dat"'
```

If the variable needs to be declared outside the statement:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000) 
DECLARE @var1 int
SELECT @var1 = 10
SET @cmd='"select '+CAST(@var1 AS VARCHAR(10))+'"' 
SELECT @sql = 'bcp '+@cmd+' queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS';
exec xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Comment: I don't find how can I do export values to .txt file in your answer, but I tried execute the query you have given with `BCP` export but it's not working, Is there any other way I can do this.

Comment: I found somewhere else:

EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "[querystatement]" queryout "c:\spt_values.dat"'

Did you use the queryout option?

Comment: It is working If I use like this: declare @cmd varchar(1000) declare @sql varchar(8000) set @cmd='"DECLARE @var1 int;SELECT @var1 = 10;select @var1"' SELECT @sql = 'bcp '+@cmd+' queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'; exec xp_cmdshell @sql; But I want declare and assign variable `@var1` outside quotes

Comment: because am going to get value from another table in a variable and export that variable's value to .txt file.

Comment: @niren added another option to the answer, edited from your comment

Comment: I tried to execute your updated code, it gives me error:"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '"select ' to data type int." then I changed `int` to `varchar(100)` and used `select @var1='text'` but It again gives me error:"Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'text'."

Comment: CAST(@var1 AS VARCHAR(10))
or in case of text add quotes (2x singlequotes):
    SET @cmd='"select '''+CAST(@var1 AS VARCHAR(10))+'''"'

Comment: thank you for your answer it is working. one more doubt what should I use in case of table datatype, so that I can get entire table there. **Note:** I don't want to use option `out` instead of `queryout` for directly use table name.

Comment: @niren using a table datatype I don't know. I quess the query inside the quotes does not recognize the table variables outside the bcp command, but have not tested this. Maybe use of a temp table (#TableName) might work? If not, post a new question.