# export table sql to .txt with c#

Tags: sql, text, export

I think I have a fairly simple question.  I just need to know how to export fields from a table in an sql database using either asp.net or C#?  Anyway to do this would be good.

I suppose I am looking for something like this, but perhaps simpler:
[Export values from SQL Server to txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634673/export-values-from-sql-server-to-txt-file)

Whatever the case, I am trying to get values from a database to a .txt, like by pressing a button in asp.net or C#, based on criteria (like between certain dates, from a date field, or starting at a certain date with a certain user, and exporting a certain number of them).  Any suggestions would help.

If I used the following code, what would I need to change so that if I wanted to select a certain column, like Note, in the database, and Date column, what would I need to do?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

public partial class ExportText : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYLearningConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblUsers", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ExportToText(ds.Tables[0], "DataTable");


    }

    protected void ExportToText(DataTable dataTable, string fileName)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            context.Response.Write(column.ColumnName + ",");
        }
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString() + ",");
            }
            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".txt");
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need a one-off solution or a permanent (run regularly) solution? Also, please tell us which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I need a run regularly solution.  I am using MS SQL.