# Export @tempTable to .txt file in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Check my last question [Export values from SQL Server to txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634673/export-values-from-sql-server-to-txt-file?noredirect=1#comment27439276_18634673). I can able to export values to .txt file with my last question. I want to do export `@tempTable` to .txt file. How can I do this?

**Edit:** My Requirement: I want to export only updated data from a table to .txt file, say user insert 10 new rows of data in existing table, I want that 10 rows to be there in .txt file. I used Inserted table in trigger to get updated rows, when I try to export to .txt file from `bcp`, I can't since I don't know the full context of inserted table([database].[schema].[tableName]). So I decided to have inserted table data in `@tempTable` to export .txt file.

This is I suppose to do [export inserted table data to .txt file in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628502/export-inserted-table-data-to-txt-file-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

you could simply load the memory table into a regular table an then use your code for export that you already have

```
select * into queryout from @tempTable
-- your code from step 1
drop table queryout
```

here is an updated version of your trigger which should do the work

```
create trigger monitorTest1 on test for insert as 
declare @sql varchar(8000); 
select * into tempTable from inserted
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from test2.dbo.tempTable" queryout C:\temp\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S localhost'
exec xp_cmdshell @sql
drop table tempTable
```

Comment: `create trigger monitorTest1 on test 
for insert 
as
create table tempTable(name varchar(100),id int);
insert into tempTable select * from inserted;

declare @sql varchar(8000);
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from test2.dbo.tempTable" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS';
exec xp_cmdshell @sql;
drop table tempTable;
go` I tried like this, but it is causing infinite loop of execution(not finish execution, keep on running) when I try to insert value in `test` table

Comment: `create trigger monitorTest1 on test 
after insert 
as
select * into queryout from inserted;
declare @sql varchar(8000);
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from queryout" queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS';
exec xp_cmdshell @sql;
drop table queryout;
go` I tried your suggestion as well, but same result(keep on executing never complete).

Comment: I tried your answer: I have created trigger like you say in your updated answer for test table and I try insert value in test table, the result: it is keep on executing never complete.

Comment: on my server it's running maybe 5 seconds. Hmm.... you already have executed succesfully a xp_cmdshell command withhin the SQL MGMT Studio as i asume. did you see something in the sqlserver log??