# Using bcp through a trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp, xp-cmdshell

The purpose of the trigger is exporting an specific data from a table with bcp after inserting data on that table, so I thought doing it in this way, I know that the trigger waits for bcp, that is waiting for a lock on the table to be released, but that lock is held until after the trigger, and for this reason it doesn't work. How can I do it? or do I need to add some function or something for that works?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER] on [TABLE] after INSERT AS BEGIN 
   DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(1000) 
   SET @CMD = 'cd.. && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" "SELECT TOP 1 CODE FROM[TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK)   ORDER BY ID DESC" queryout "\\FOLDER\FOLDER\FILE.txt" -T -c -S "[SERVERNAME]"'
   EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @CMD 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `bcp` in a trigger. Even if you could get it to work it will slow down your database, probably to the point where it will not be usable. `bcp` is a command line utility and should be treated as one

I recommend that you use an [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent) to execute extra actions on a scheduled or triggered basis

You can also read [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72267/) tutorial that will help you get started with Agents

If you do not have SQL Server Agent (Express does not include it), then you have a few other options:

- Write your own Agent. [Here is an example](https://standalonesqlagent.codeplex.com/)
- Call a stored procedure after insert. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628502/export-inserted-table-data-to-txt-file-in-sql-server) used that method to solve similar problem to the one you posted
- Use a stored procedure to write data and process the export code
- Use a scheduled task processes data on a schedule (this is where `bcp` can be used without killing server performance)

Comment: Hi, is SQL Server Agent available on SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'll update my answer with alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but you could try changing to an INSTEAD OF trigger and do the INSERT and bcp within the trigger

I suspect this may circumvent the lock on the table.

further reading - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/37db1d/creating-and-managing-triggers-in-sql-server-20052008/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed to INSTEAD OF, but it's the same, when I execute the trigger, it hangs...